React-Native: Image picker complain with new Google MEDIA policy
I'm using typical library (react-native-image-picker) for working with media in react-native. With new google policy this library doesn't match. Official Google explanation:

For a more privacy preserving experience for users, we’re introducing
the Photo and Video Permissions policy to reduce the number of apps
permitted to request broad photo/video permissions (READ_MEDIA_IMAGES
and READ_MEDIA_VIDEO). Apps may only access photos and videos for
purposes directly related to app functionality. Apps that have a
one-time or infrequent need to access these files are requested to use
a system picker, such as the Android photo picker. (effective August
31, 2024)

Reference: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/13986130#photo-and-video-permissions
Does somebody have any ideas? I'm not familiar with Kotlin for working with native code + react-native. Maybe somebody know libraries which match with this new policy or maybe another solutions?

Check out the Broad access to photos and videos are also subject to the following requirements section. You'll have to let google know why you're requesting the permission. If the user denies it, use the native photo picker to select the media files.

If you haven't added the permissions, you need to add these permissions in the AndroidManifest and request the media permissions before accessing the media files.
Haven't checked out the libraries that provide native photo picker implementation.
